# Spider for technology profiling - identify Content Management System

Tags: full-text-search, web-crawler, search-engine

I'm looking for a web spider that can crawl links (start from a specific url and follow links to other domains) and identify sites that have a directory called "abc" that has a page title that includes "123".

This may sound shady so let me explain, it's a tool to identify websites that use a certain CMS so I can build up a prospect list for CMS support services.
The alternate approach is a spider that can identify occurrences of certain strings in html that are familiar to this CMS.

Such services are provided by builtwith.com and wappalyzer.com though these commercial solutions are massively pricey and I'd like to first explore open source solutions.

Comment: Data mining = statistical data analysis. Not collection. You're looking for a classic focused web crawler.

Comment: Also note that **questions asking for a tool or off-site resource** are considered off-topic. Your question is *not* a *programming* question.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. The approach I will probably take is a web-based crawler - I'm looking into a Elasticsearch / Scrapy combo right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a search engine.

Many search engines allow queries such as `intitle:123 inurl:abc`.

But beware, they tend to block requests that are known to aim at security issues. Like the Santy and myDoom worms, which relied on Google to find vulnerable phpBB installations.

Craling all of the interwebs yourself will take a *lot* of time, you know...

If you don't need the latest data, and have some bucks to spare, you could also process the commonsCrawl on AWS.

Comment: Thanks I've obtained good yet limited results using monstercrawler + webcrawler.com - they certainly yield a more comprehensive list than can be obtained from Google though given the profiling requirements needed to accurately identify this CMS a standard engine won't cut it.